# Интерактивное SVG колесо

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

Есть вот такое колесо:

[image: Колесо]

Т.е. нужно сделать 3 сплошных circle, поместить друг в друга и второй разделить на 6 частей.

Цвет элемента будет меняться по нажатию, т.е. плавно из серого переходить в градиент и добавляться верхний border.

Подскажите, как лучше такое реализовать, на SVG или же Canvas?
Вот эти иконки будут интерактивно меняться в зависимости от выбранной части, также текст в центре.

Comment: на svg конечно проще

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в svg вообще не понимаю как это делать :(

Comment: можно в редакторе, можно по формулам, могу показать как по формулам...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ как вам удобно, хочу понять как это делать, заготовки есть разные, кто-то плодит div, кто-то через css задают миллион свойств
Если на svg практичнее всего сделать - я бы сделал так, но как ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Решение SVG + CSS

Окружность можно разделить на 6 отдельных секторов с помощью команды `Elliptical Arc` для `path`  [подробнее здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=900#comm_a)

- Рисуем один сектор

```css
svg {
  height: 440px;
  width: 440px;
}
.sector {
  fill: #5F5E5F;
  stroke: #BFBFBF;
  stroke-width:2;
} 
:hover.sector {
 fill:#9F45E2;
 stroke-width:6;
 stroke:#9F45E2;
 transition: fill 0.5s, stroke-width 0.5s;
 
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110'>

  <path class="sector " d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z' />
</svg>
```

- Добавляем ещё 5 секторов

```css
svg {
  height: 440px;
  width: 440px;
}
.sector {
  fill: #5F5E5F;
  stroke: #BFBFBF;
  stroke-width:2;
} 
:hover.sector {
 fill:#9F45E2;
 stroke-width:6;
 stroke:#9F45E2;
 transition: fill 0.5s, stroke-width 0.5s;
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110'>
  
  <!-- Блок секторов --> 
  <path class="sector " d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z' />
  <path class="sector" d='M55,55 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30z' />
  <path class="sector" d='M55,55 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55z' />
  <path class="sector" d='M55,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69z' />
  <path class="sector " d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z' />
  <path class="sector" d='M55,55 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55z' />
  
</svg>
```

Добавляем окружности для создания центральной части, добавляем текст и иконки.

Иконки брал [здесь](https://www.materialui.co/icons)

Для придания  нужного размера иконкам используем `scale(0.7)`

Для позиционирования икон используется команда `translate(X Y)`

Ниже полный код:

```css
svg {
  height: 440px;
  width: 440px;
}
.sector {
  fill: #5F5E5F;
  stroke: #BFBFBF;
  stroke-width:2;
} 
:hover.sector {
 fill:#9F45E2;
 stroke-width:6;
 stroke:#9F45E2;
 transition: fill 0.5s, stroke-width 0.5s;
 
}
#F {
  fill: #5F5E5F;
  stroke: #BFBFBF;
} 
#S {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #BFBFBF;
   stroke-width:5;
}
#T {
  fill: #707070;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width:3;
}
.icon {
fill:none;
stroke:#CCCACD;
transition: fill 0.5s;
}
:hover.icon {
fill:#9F45E2;
}
</style>
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 110 110'>
  
  <!-- Блок секторов --> 
  <path class="sector " d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z' />
  <path class="sector" d='M55,55 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30z' />
  <path class="sector" d='M55,55 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55z' />
  <path class="sector" d='M55,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69z' />
  <path class="sector " d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z' />
  <path class="sector" d='M55,55 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55z' />
  
 <circle id="F" cx='55' cy='55' r='25' /> 
  <circle id="S" cx='55' cy='55' r='23'  /> 
   <circle id="T" cx='55' cy='55' r='22'  /> 
    <circle id="Big" cx='55' cy='55' r='50' fill="none" stroke="#BFBFBF" stroke-width="2" /> 
  
  
  <text x="55" y="55" font-size="5" fill="white" font-weight="bold"  text-anchor="middle"  > Текст в круге </text> 
  
  <!-- Блок иконок --> 
 <path class="icon" transform="translate(47 10) scale(0.7)" d="M12 10c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm7-7H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-1.75 9c0 .23-.02.46-.05.68l1.48 1.16c.13.11.17.3.08.45l-1.4 2.42c-.09.15-.27.21-.43.15l-1.74-.7c-.36.28-.76.51-1.18.69l-.26 1.85c-.03.17-.18.3-.35.3h-2.8c-.17 0-.32-.13-.35-.29l-.26-1.85c-.43-.18-.82-.41-1.18-.69l-1.74.7c-.16.06-.34 0-.43-.15l-1.4-2.42c-.09-.15-.05-.34.08-.45l1.48-1.16c-.03-.23-.05-.46-.05-.69 0-.23.02-.46.05-.68l-1.48-1.16c-.13-.11-.17-.3-.08-.45l1.4-2.42c.09-.15.27-.21.43-.15l1.74.7c.36-.28.76-.51 1.18-.69l.26-1.85c.03-.17.18-.3.35-.3h2.8c.17 0 .32.13.35.29l.26 1.85c.43.18.82.41 1.18.69l1.74-.7c.16-.06.34 0 .43.15l1.4 2.42c.09.15.05.34-.08.45l-1.48 1.16c.03.23.05.46.05.69z"/>
  
   
  <path class="icon" transform="translate(80 27) scale(0.7)" d="M12 6v3l4-4-4-4v3c-4.42 0-8 3.58-8 8 0 1.57.46 3.03 1.24 4.26L6.7 14.8c-.45-.83-.7-1.79-.7-2.8 0-3.31 2.69-6 6-6zm6.76 1.74L17.3 9.2c.44.84.7 1.79.7 2.8 0 3.31-2.69 6-6 6v-3l-4 4 4 4v-3c4.42 0 8-3.58 8-8 0-1.57-.46-3.03-1.24-4.26z"/>
  
   <path class="icon" transform="translate(80 66) scale(0.7)" d="M11.99 2C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zm4.24 16L12 15.45 7.77 18l1.12-4.81-3.73-3.23 4.92-.42L12 5l1.92 4.53 4.92.42-3.73 3.23L16.23 18z"/> 
 
</svg>
```

### JS

Разбить круг на любое количество секторов можно с помощью `javascript`, который реализует формулу  `Elliptical Arc` для `path`

- Задаются переменные `fromAngle`, `toAngle` начального и конечного
  угла сектора
- Задаются переменные для расчета начальных и конечных координат
  сектора  `fromCoordX`, `fromCoordY`, `toCoordX`, `toCoordY`
- Вызов функции для рисования 6 секторов - `createSector(55, 55, 50, 6);`, 
  где
  `55` координаты центра окружности
  `50` - радиус окружности
  `6` - количество секторов

```js
var fromAngle, toAngle, fromCoordX, fromCoordY, toCoordX, toCoordY, path, d;

function createSector(cx, cy, r, part) {
  for (var i = 0; i < part; i++) {
    path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    fromAngle = i * 360 / part;
    toAngle = (i + 1) * 360 / part;
    fromCoordX = cx + (r * Math.cos(fromAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    fromCoordY = cy + (r * Math.sin(fromAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    toCoordX = cx + (r * Math.cos(toAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    toCoordY = cy + (r * Math.sin(toAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    d = 'M' + cx + ',' + cy + ' L' + fromCoordX + ',' + fromCoordY + ' A' + r + ',' + r + ' 0 0,1 ' + toCoordX + ',' + toCoordY + 'z';
    path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
    document.getElementById('pie').appendChild(path);
  }
}

createSector(55, 55, 50, 6);
```

```css
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
path {
   fill: #5F5E5F;
  stroke: #BFBFBF;
  stroke-width:2;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 110 110" id="pie"></svg>
```

**8 секторов**

```js
var fromAngle, toAngle, fromCoordX, fromCoordY, toCoordX, toCoordY, path, d;

function createSector(cx, cy, r, part) {
  for (var i = 0; i < part; i++) {
    path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    fromAngle = i * 360 / part;
    toAngle = (i + 1) * 360 / part;
    fromCoordX = cx + (r * Math.cos(fromAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    fromCoordY = cy + (r * Math.sin(fromAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    toCoordX = cx + (r * Math.cos(toAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    toCoordY = cy + (r * Math.sin(toAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    d = 'M' + cx + ',' + cy + ' L' + fromCoordX + ',' + fromCoordY + ' A' + r + ',' + r + ' 0 0,1 ' + toCoordX + ',' + toCoordY + 'z';
    path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
    document.getElementById('pie').appendChild(path);
  }
}

createSector(55, 55, 50, 8);
```

```css
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
path {
  fill: #5F5E5F;
  stroke: #BFBFBF;
  stroke-width:2;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 110 110" id="pie"></svg>
```

**12 секторов**

```js
var fromAngle, toAngle, fromCoordX, fromCoordY, toCoordX, toCoordY, path, d;

function createSector(cx, cy, r, part) {
  for (var i = 0; i < part; i++) {
    path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    fromAngle = i * 360 / part;
    toAngle = (i + 1) * 360 / part;
    fromCoordX = cx + (r * Math.cos(fromAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    fromCoordY = cy + (r * Math.sin(fromAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    toCoordX = cx + (r * Math.cos(toAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    toCoordY = cy + (r * Math.sin(toAngle * Math.PI / 180));
    d = 'M' + cx + ',' + cy + ' L' + fromCoordX + ',' + fromCoordY + ' A' + r + ',' + r + ' 0 0,1 ' + toCoordX + ',' + toCoordY + 'z';
    path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
    document.getElementById('pie').appendChild(path);
  }
}

createSector(55, 55, 50, 12);
```

```css
svg {
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
path {
 fill: #5F5E5F;
  stroke: #BFBFBF;
  stroke-width:2;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 110 110" id="pie"></svg>
```

Comment: спасибо, за разъяснение!

Answer (score 4):

Сверстал что-то подобное, при помощи синусов да косинусов. чтобы получить прямо точь в точь что и в макете надо еще с этим посидеть. пока так, для понимания я думаю хватит.

```js
let items = ['','','','','',''],
    r1 = 90, 
    r2 = 50, 
    step = Math.PI*2/items.length;
    
let activate = el => document.querySelectorAll('.arc')
  .forEach(arc => arc.style.strokeWidth = (arc.classList.contains(el.id) ? 4:0) + 'px');
                             
let cs = a => [Math.cos(a), Math.sin(a)]

let icon = (e, i) => {
  let p = cs(i*step + step/2), r = (r1/2 + r2/2);
  return `<text x='${p[0]*r}' y='${p[1]*r}'>${e}</text>`;
}

let grid = (e, i) => {
    let p1 = cs(i*step);
    return `<path class='grid' d='
      M${p1[0]*(r1)} ${p1[1]*(r1)}
      L${p1[0]*(r2)} ${p1[1]*(r2)}
    '></path>`;
}


let arc = (e, i) => {
    let p1 = cs(i*step), p2 = cs(i*step + step), r = r1+2.5;
    return `<path class='arc s${i}' d='
      M${p1[0]*r} ${p1[1]*r}
      A${r} ${r} 0 0 1 ${p2[0]*r} ${p2[1]*r}
    '></path>`;
}

let sector = (e, i) => {
  let p1 = cs(i*step), p2 = cs(i*step + step);
  return `<path class='sector' id='s${i}' onmouseover='activate(this)' d='
      M${p1[0]*r2} ${p1[1]*r2} 
      L${p1[0]*r1} ${p1[1]*r1} 
      A${r1} ${r1} 0 0 1 ${p2[0]*r1} ${p2[1]*r1} 
      L${p2[0]*r2} ${p2[1]*r2} 
      A${r2} ${r2} 0 0 0 ${p1[0]*r2} ${p1[1]*r2}
    '></path>`
}

svg.innerHTML += items.map(sector).join('')
svg.innerHTML += items.map(icon).join('')
svg.innerHTML += `<circle r=${r1}></circle><circle r=${r2}></circle>`;
svg.innerHTML += items.map(grid).join('')
svg.innerHTML += items.map(arc).join('')
```

```css
path.sector {
  fill: url(#gradient);
  cursor: pointer;
  fill-opacity:0.5;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

path.arc {
  fill: none;
  stroke: purple;
  stroke-width: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

path.sector:hover {
  fill-opacity:1;
}

text {
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
  pointer-events: none;
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: lightgray;
  pointer-events: none;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

path.grid {
  stroke: lightgray;
  pointer-events: none;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewbox="-100 -100 200 200" height="90vh">
  <linearGradient id="gradient" x2="1" y2="1">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="purple" />
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="garkgray" />
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

Comment: спасибо!
разделители через dash-array можно сделать ?
или тоже через формулы

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE ну если получится обводками - так конечно проще, но у Вас такой макет, что боюсь не выйдет...

Comment: а каким образом это сделать, отступами между элементами?, но ведь они не задаются, а как задавать я вообще не знаю(

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE  я бы еще линий поверх добавил по тем же координатам

Answer (score 2):

В общем я только с градиентной заливкой на hover завис ..а так все хотелки выполнены

Если что то не ясно спрашивайте, не применял алгоритмов и само изготовление не сложное

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">

<svg width="400" height="400" viewbox="0 0 4 4">

     <defs>
      <style>
       .hover{
        stroke-opacity: 0;
       }
       g:hover .hover{
        stroke-opacity: 1;
       }
       g:hover text{
        fill: red;
       }
      </style>
     </defs>

      <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1.05" 
       fill="none"
       stroke="lightgreen"
       stroke-width="1.06"/>

       <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="0.45" 
       fill="lightgreen"/>
       <text font-size="0.1"
       x="1.66" 
       y="2.05"
       font-family="sans-serif"> текст в центре </text>

<g>    
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1" 
    fill="none" 
    stroke="lightblue"
    stroke-width="1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1 6" 
    stroke-dashoffset="-0.01"/>
    <text x="2.7" y="2.7"
    font-family="FontAwesome"
    font-size="0.5px" 
    fill="lightgreen"></text><!--android-->
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1.5"
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-width="0.1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1.49 9"
    stroke-dashoffset="-0.01" class="hover"/>
</g>
<g>
      <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1" 
    fill="none" 
    stroke="lightblue"
    stroke-width="1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1 6" 
    stroke-dashoffset="-1.05"/>
    <text x="1.7" y="3.2"
      font-family="FontAwesome"
      fill="lightgreen"
    font-size="0.5px" 
    ></text> <!--руки-->
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1.5"
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-width="0.1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1.49 9"
    stroke-dashoffset="-1.6" class="hover"/>
</g>
<g>

    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1" 
    fill="none" 
    stroke="lightblue"
    stroke-width="1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1 6" 
    stroke-dashoffset="-2.1"/>
    <text x="0.85" y="2.6"
      font-family="FontAwesome"
      fill="lightgreen"
    font-size="0.5px" 
    ></text> <!--замок-->
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1.5"
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-width="0.1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1.49 9"
    stroke-dashoffset="-3.17" class="hover"/>
</g>
<g>

   <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1" 
    fill="none" 
    stroke="lightblue"
    stroke-width="1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1 6" 
    stroke-dashoffset="3.86"/>
    <text x="0.85" y="1.7"
      font-family="FontAwesome"
      fill="lightgreen"
    font-size="0.5px" 
    ></text> <!--душ-->
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1.5"
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-width="0.1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1.49 9"
    stroke-dashoffset="-4.71" class="hover"/>
</g>
<g>

    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1" 
    fill="none" 
    stroke="lightblue"
    stroke-width="1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1 6" 
    stroke-dashoffset="2.8"/>
    <text x="1.75" y="1.2"
      font-family="FontAwesome"
      fill="lightgreen"
    font-size="0.5px" 
    ></text> <!--бинокль-->
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1.5"
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-width="0.1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1.49 9"
    stroke-dashoffset="-6.3"  class="hover"/>
</g>
<g>

     <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1" 
    fill="none" 
    stroke="lightblue"
    stroke-width="1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1 6" 
    stroke-dashoffset="1.75"/>
   <text x="2.5" y="1.7"
      font-family="FontAwesome"
      fill="lightgreen"
    font-size="0.5px" 
    ></text> <!--велосипед -->
    <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1.5"
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    stroke-width="0.1" 
    stroke-dasharray="1.49 9"
    stroke-dashoffset="-7.9" class="hover"/>
</g> 

 </svg>
```

Comment: спасибо, хорошее решение

Comment: @MaximLensky И у меня было первое желание реализовать секторную, цветную обводку с помощью `stroke-dasharray` (+), но захотелось попробовать другие варианты

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  да я люблю по проще ...без гемороя ...к примеру посмотри на  hover у тебя в примере ...и поймёшь о чём я, а автор вопроса самостоятельно это не исправит ,иначе этого вопроса не задавал бы